# Android programmatically added ListPreference has missing title

Tags: java, android, android-preferences

In my `PreferenceFragment` I have a ListPreference that I add programmatically in my PreferenceScreen like this

```
ListPreference groupPref = new ListPreference(getActivity());
groupPref.setTitle("Aktuelle Gruppe");
groupPref.setKey("groupObjectId");
groupPref.setEntries(entries);
groupPref.setEntryValues(values);

PreferenceScreen screen = this.getPreferenceScreen();
screen.addPreference(groupPref);
```

This works generally and the Preference has a title in the list of preferences. But it has no title when the choosing dialog opens.

[image: screenshot]

How to make it show a title in that dialog?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Call `setDialogTitle()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/DialogPreference.html#setDialogTitle(java.lang.CharSequence)). `setTitle()` sets the title in the row in the `PreferenceScreen`.